Proving the inequality $\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a} + \frac{abc(\lambda + 1)^3}{(a + \lambda b)(b + \lambda c)(c + \lambda a)} \geq 4$

Prove the inequality
$$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a} + \frac{abc(\lambda + 1)^3}{(a + \lambda b)(b + \lambda c)(c + \lambda a)} \geq 4$$
for positive real numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, and $\lambda$.

I  aimed to prove the inequality:
$\frac{abc(\lambda + 1)^3}{(a + \lambda b)(b + \lambda c)(c + \lambda a)} \geq 1$,
$abc(\lambda + 1)^3 \geq (a + \lambda b)(b + \lambda c)(c + \lambda a)$.
Case Analysis for $\lambda = 1$: For simplicity, I tested the inequality with $\lambda = 1$. In this case, the inequality becomes:
$\frac{8abc}{(a + b)(b + c)(c + a)} \geq 1$,
$8abc \geq (a + b)(b + c)(c + a)$.
Which is obviously true by AM-GM
The inequality is straightforward to verify when $a = b = c$, or for specific values of $\lambda$ (e.g., $\lambda = 1$ under symmetry). However, a complete proof for all positive real numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, and $\lambda$ remains challenging without further constraints.
How can I rigorously proof this? Which iniquality I should use I don't have any clue.

Have you tried analysing similar cases, for example when lambda equals -1?

Note, $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)\geqslant 8abc$ by AM-GM, not the reverse which is what you have. You have to "mix" the four terms, just the fourth term alone will not give you any useful result (hint: see what happens when any of the variables  $\to 0$).

Let's rewrite our sum a bit
$$
S = \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a} + \frac{abc(\lambda + 1)^3}{(a + \lambda b)(b + \lambda c)(c + \lambda a)} = 
$$
$$
= \left[\frac{1}{1+\lambda} \left( \frac{a + \lambda b}{b} + \frac{b + \lambda c}{c} + \frac{c + \lambda a}{a} \right) + \frac{abc(\lambda + 1)^3}{(a + \lambda b)(b + \lambda c)(c + \lambda a)}\right] + 
$$
$$
+\frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda} \left[ \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a} - 3\right] = 
$$
$$
= S_1 + S_2.
$$
Now apply AM-GM inequality to the terms in the first square brackets to get
$$
S_1 \ge 4 \sqrt[4]{1} = 4.
$$
Applying AM-GM to the terms in second square brackets we get
$$
S_2 = \frac{\lambda}{1 + \lambda} \left( \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a} - 3 \right) \ge 0.
$$
Combining these two results we get
$$
S \ge 4.
$$
Q.E.D.
